# Как сгенерировать список или массив в Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

Имею исходный рандомный массив:

```
np.array([0, 1, 2]).
```

Нужно получить два ряда чисел (списков или одномерных массивов), в которых повторяются элементы исходного массива следующим образом:

```
np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]) 

np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]).
```

Чтобы проще было представить, это плоские транспонированные массивы:

```
np.array([[0, 1, 2],
          [0, 1, 2],
          [0, 1, 2]]).ravel()

np.array([[0, 0, 0],
          [1, 1, 1],
          [2, 2, 2]].ravel()
```

Для формирования таких рядов чисел использую индексирование, но это медленно:

```
import numpy as np

# Задание индексов
ind_1 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
ind_2 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])

# Далее должен идти бесконечный цикл 'while True':  
for i in range(1):
    a = np.random.sample(3)
    # Длительный процесс формирования массивов m_1 и m_2:
    m_1 = a[ind_1]
    m_2 = a[ind_2]
```

Имеется ли более быстрый способ сгенерировать такие ряды чисел m_1 и m_2 другим способом, например, с использованием генерации списков?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 1, 2])

print(np.tile(a, 3))
print(np.repeat(a, 3))
```

Вывод:

```
[0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2]
[0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2]
```

Comment: для массива длиной 1000 "np.tile(a, 1000)" быстрее в 3,3 раза; "np.repeat(a, 1000)" быстрее в 1,5 раза (для выборки из 200 повторений)

Comment: Имеется ли более быстрый способ?

Comment: @bluesky, придумайте другой алгоритм. Зачем вам такие большие массивы с кучей одинаковых элементов? Можно оставить оригинальные массивы. Например, в первом случае берите остаток от деления желаемого индекса и по нему получайте элемент в оригинальном массиве.